# How to implement a custom rules for pushing changes on hg or git in a way that is easy to deploy?

Tags: version-control, githooks, mercurial-hook

Use case: you want to prevent people from pushing to trunk when trunk is in marked as red - in this case you want to ask them to confirm before accepting this.

The problem is local `.hg/hgrc` hooks is that only you are getting them and this is not an acceptable approach when you want to implement something like this for all developers.

How is possible to implement such thing in a way that would work for everybody.